# Difference between confidence intervals using standard error and standard deviation.

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

Can someone please explain the difference between an interval built by:

x̅ $\pm$ (Critical Value) X (Standard Error)

and

x̅ $\pm$ (Critical Value) X (Standard Deviation)

It's not clear to me when to use which.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many kinds of confidence intervals for a variety of population
parameters. My guess is that the one described here is what you have in mind:

If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a random sample from a normal distribution
with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ (both parameters unknown),
then a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is of the form
$$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$$
where $\bar X$ is the sample mean $S$ is the sample standard deviation,
and $t^*$ cuts 2.5% of the area from the upper tail of Student's t
distribution with $\nu = n-1$ degrees of freedom. The *standard error*
is $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n},$ estimated as $S/\sqrt{n}.$

---

*Notes:*

(1) In the situation above, if $\sigma$ is known and $\mu$ is unknown, then
a 95% confidence interval (CI) for $\mu$ is of the form $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ Because $\sigma$ is known, it is not necessary
to estimate the standard error $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ and one may use the
standard normal distribution (instead of a t distribution) to get the
value 1.96.

(2) There *are* CIs in which the standard error happens to be
the same as the standard deviation. (One example is a CI for Poisson 
mean $\lambda.$ However, I doubt that is what you have in mind.)

(3) A 95% confidence interval for normal SD $\sigma$ is based on the chi-squared distribution.
Because that distribution is not symmetrical, values cutting 2.5%
of the probability from each tail (separately) are used, and the CI does
is not of the form (point estimate) $\pm$ (standard error).